# ITFoxTec Saml2 Cookie name

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I noticed the Cookie.Name property isn't set in the AddSaml2 method.  This results in cookies with the name beginning with a ".".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahhZL.png)

Will there be any updates to add that property to the method?

The only answer to setting it I can find on stackoverflow suggests creating a custom extension ([ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 with NET 5.0- Set cookie name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895825/itfoxtec-saml-2-0-with-net-5-0-set-cookie-name)).

So my question is will the library be updated to handle this without a custom extension?

Answer (score 0):

I think cookies starting with an "." is default .NET behaver.

I do not have plans for adding a cookie name property. The best solution is to use an extension.

Comment: Ok, the reason I asked is because we run 2 web applications that our users may run in separate tabs on the same browser.  Because the cookie name is the same in both applications, the user cannot use both apps.

Comment: Okay - yes you need to change the cookie name, if the two web applications run on the same domain. Otherwise it should work using the same cookie name.